# Why key up is not working for particular word only ? Is this bug in Jquery itself

Tags: jquery

On Key up i am doing a Search (on entering of two characters the search should work)
The Search is working fine expect for the word **Spine** (the word spine is not getting searched until 3 characters are typed)

This is my code

```
$('#filtertags').keyup(function() {
  var tr = $('#catstable tbody td'); //keep this outside as we have to show all elements on backspace
  if ($(this).val().length >= 2) {

    // $('#errmsgnotags').hide();
    var noElemtag = true;
    var val = $.trim(this.value).toLowerCase();
    el = tr.find('label').filter(function() {
      return this.innerHTML.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) >= 0;
    }).closest('td');
    if (el.length >= 1) {
      noElemtag = false;
    }
    tr.not(el).fadeOut();
    el.fadeIn();
    //  if (noElemtag) $('#errmsgnotags').html('No Results Matched').show();
  } else {
    tr.fadeIn(); //show all if length does not match the required number of characters
    // $('#errmsgnotags').hide();
  }
})
```

The other keywords are being searched for two characters except for the word spine 
http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/381/

Comment: Well, seriously? Guys, this is definitely not a typo! LoL. It took everyone of us at least 10 mins to figure out why was it happening.

Answer (score 2):

You need to search effectively for the text, not their HTML. This is because, all the elements have `Sp` in them.

```
<span>
```

You can make it work by changing the `.html()` or `.innerHTML` to `.text()`.

```
$(this).text().toLowerCase()
```

Here:

```
el = tr.find('label').filter(function() {
  return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(val) >= 0;
}).closest('td');
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j57wbt3b/**

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here `this.innerHTML.toLowerCase()`.

The `innerHtml` of all your elements contains `<span>`, so `sp` matches all elements.

You could use `$(this).text().toLowerCase()` instead.

Comment: Ha! Everyone got to know at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your `this.innerHTML.toLowerCase()` returns something like `two<span></span>` and when entering `sp` it *does match <**sp**an>*

Answer (score 0):

this portion of your code is problematic: `this.innerHTML.toLowerCase()`

this returns the following :

- `one<span></span>`
- `two<span></span>`
- `three<span></span>`
- `spine1<span></span>`
- `four<span></span>`

Quickest change would be to replace

```
return this.innerHTML.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) >= 0;
```

with

```
return this.textContent.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) >= 0;
```

Have a look at this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/392/

Comment: This won't work, if people need to check for middle words. Let's say, `ou` should select `four`, which will not happen.